# TFS 2010 Clone Team Project with History (or something like it)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've been going through here reading about similar question, and I haven't been able to find what I was looking for. I hope you all can help me understand this better.

Where I work, I've been trying to take our 'mega' team project and break it up into more manageable team projects, so that we can build only what we need. I've done a proof of concept and it works great. Basically I isolate a solution (sln) as a team project (and all the projects that go with it), and then I have another team project that's the common files (dlls or other sln project from the outsides). This was the best result after I went down the path of researching baseless merges (which is fun, and ended up not working as expected). Anyway, no baseless merge...

Update / Edit... mega breakdown:

```
$(MegaTeamProj)
$(MegaTeamProj)\Common\
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\Aproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\Bproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\thesol.sln
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\Aproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\Bproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\thesol.sln
```

Attempting to break this out into:

```
$(Common)

$(SolutionA)\Aproject
$(SolutionA)\Bproject
$(SolutionA)\thesol.sln

and

$(SolutionB)\Aproject
$(SolutionB)\Bproject
$(SolutionB)\thesol.sln
```

Where I struggle now is creating a new team project that retains all the history of the check in for that solution. If I were using svn, I could just clone the repository folder and delete what I didn't need and commit (for example of my strategy thinking with TFS). Anyway, another sticking point is there is a 3rd party who actually maintains our TFS stuff (technical term :) ). So I have admin abilities through Team Explorer to Create new projects (with reports) and so on...

I did try moving the folders / files (via the UI in the Source Control Explorer), and the history didn't not follow over to the new team project. Obviously the history does migrate if I move folders or files within the same project.

How have you all approached this?

Thanks,
Kelly

Comment: Can you expand on "I've been trying to take our 'mega' team project and break it up into more manageable team projects, so that we can build only what we need." a bit. I don't understand why having multiple solutions in a team project were causing you to build what you didn't need.

Comment: Hi @Betty, I updated it to reflect The TFS mega project, and how (ideally) I'd break it out into smaller team projects. Why we need to break it down is that each solution is for a main application. When dealing with builds, the goal is traditionally only build the app you are working on. Equally when doing build, you only want to the build to check out the items it needs to complete its task. In our case, we have all those other solutions which aren't important when building the app we're concerned about. This also reduces build time. Does this help you?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't setting your work space correctly in your build definition, you should be limiting the workspace to the solution folder ($(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\).  I'd also recommend against referencing anything outside the solution folder and creating custom NuGet packages instead. Microsoft actually recommend against having multiple Team Projects in most situations (http://blog.hinshelwood.com/one-team-project-collection-to-rule-them-allconsolidating-team-projects/).

Comment: Also just a note, there isn't a way to move folders with their history to other Team Projects.  You could use TFS Integration Platform to perform a migration (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/08/09/tfs-migration-tools-wandering-into-the-caves-of-migration-scenarios.aspx), but it has downsides.

Comment: I suppose it didn't make sense earlier, but these projects don't share the same release schedule. 

Anyway, all of this works. My main problem is trying to figure out a way to move, clone, or copy those folders and maintain their history into other team projects.

Comment: Research TFS Integration Platform then, it's not nice but it's the only way to migrate history.  But please also do some reading on disadvantages of multiple Team Projects.

Comment: Thanks you very much for suggesting tfs integration link @Betty. I'll have to wait and try it out tomorrow.

Comment: Alternatively branches may work cross team projects, it won't work exactly how you want but the history should still be accessible in the history windows as long as you don't delete the original project.

Comment: So we wound up just doing a copy of the folders and leaving the old stuff as legacy. I did try the tfs integration a little, and it seems nice. I feel it wouldn't have helped, but I will consider using it if it meets the challenge. Thank you again for all your suggestions @Betty.

Comment: Maybe you could create an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Betty was a wonderful help in discussing some of the issues, and I wish I could provide an answer for my question in how to migrate and preserve history. I've tried branching and moving between projects without success. It easily makes sense BTW. Each Team Project has its own sql db, and in our case the history is based off of the team project not the solutionA, B, etc... It also makes it difficult to attempt other solutions because we have a 3rd party providing us Source Control services (TFS and build agents).

In our case (where I work), it was OK with my director to copy files to a new Team Project. After we finished a release, I copied that project over. In this case our current structure remains in place. We just told our group to continue working in the new team project.

Doing so we have the following:

```
$(MegaTeamProj)
$(MegaTeamProj)\Common\
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\Aproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\Bproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionA\thesol.sln
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\Aproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\Bproject
$(MegaTeamProj)\SolutionB\thesol.sln
```

and we also have the newly created projects:

```
$(Common)

$(SolutionA)\Aproject
$(SolutionA)\Bproject
$(SolutionA)\thesol.sln

$(SolutionB)\Aproject
$(SolutionB)\Bproject
$(SolutionB)\thesol.sln
```

So now staff can continue to see old changes via MegaTeamProj, and do new dev in the respective team projects.

I do hope Microsoft things about ways to make this easier in the future, and I think between this and SVN, it makes me want to opt for it VS. TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know if I understand this correctly but

1. If you're trying to split collection i've came across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936158.aspx)
2. If you're trying to migrate a TFS collection to a new server, you can try the detach / attach method, [(Move a Team Project Collection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936138.aspx)

If you're issue is #2 all check-in history will be included too.